# How to store radio button value as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

I tried to make a multilanguage site with html and javascript.
For selecting the language I created three radio boxes (values: en, de, fr).
The words which should be displayed are stored in a javascript object.

Here is the code:

```
$('#lang-setting').on('change', function () {
var lang = $('input:checked', '#lang-setting').val();
console.log(lang);
alert(lang);
$('#latitude-n').html(lang.latitude);
$('#longitude-n').html(lang.longitude);
$('#accuracy-n').html(lang.accuracy);
$('#words-n').html(lang.words);
$('#map-n').html(lang.map);
$('#test').html(de.test);
});
```

alert(lang) and console.log give the right language every time I select a language.

But: the other words don't change. They do if I replace the 'lang' with f.e. 'de' (see last code line).

Comment: lang is a string, so lang.latitude is undefined. If you have made a global object called de in window with translations, what you need to do is window[lang].latitude, which computes to de.latitude if lang === 'de'

Comment: Basically a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: any HTML to show? How does look your object at all?

Comment: @juvian Your solution worked verry well. The only thing I still don't understand is why the 'window' prefix ist needed.

Comment: Also why do you use checkoxes? So that one can read all languages at the same time?

Comment: You could also use a loop and target elements ID  by your object propertyname instead if writing all those selectors...

Comment: @AndiLeni because your language objects are window.de, window.fr, window.en (the global scope is windows, so all variables defined with global scope are stored in windows object). Still, Tessa answer is a nicer approach

Comment: @juvian  Now I understand it. Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan should be radio boxes. thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable named **lang** is a string because you're setting it to the value of the radio input, so **lang.latitude**, **lang.longitude**, **lang.accuracy**, **lang.words**, and **lang.map** are all undefined.

I'm assuming you have global variables such as **de** set since you said **de.test** works.

It would probably be easiest to put all of those languages into a single object that you can then reference by the key, or the value of the radio input. I've also added a variable that allows you to select the default language and the function that will be performing the actual html change.

```
var translate = {
    default: 'en',
    en: {
        latitude: 'latitude',
        longitude: 'longitude',
        accuracy: 'accuracy',
        words: 'words',
        map: 'map',
    },
    de: {
        latitude: '',
        longitude: '',
        accuracy: '',
        words: '',
        map: '',
    },
    fr: {
        latitude: '',
        longitude: '',
        accuracy: '',
        words: '',
        map: '',
    },
    changeText: function(lang) {
        $('#latitude-n').html(translate[lang].latitude);
        $('#longitude-n').html(translate[lang].longitude);
        $('#accuracy-n').html(translate[lang].accuracy);
        $('#words-n').html(translate[lang].words);
        $('#map-n').html(translate[lang].map);
    }
}
```

Since you didn't post the HTML of your three radio buttons, I'm going to instead give them name attributes instead of id's of with the value "lang-settings" because having duplicate id's is invalid HTML. Below is the minimal HTML for these radio buttons.

```
<input name="lang-setting" value="en" type="radio" />
<input name="lang-setting" value="de" type="radio" />
<input name="lang-setting" value="fr" type="radio" />
```

Then for your listener, I've switched it to listen for "clicks" instead of changing, because the values of the radio button isn't actually changing, they're staying as "en", "de", and "fr". I've also added the function call in document ready to run your default language selection on page load.

```
$('input[name="lang-setting"]').on('click', function(e){
    var lang = $(this).val();
    translate.changeText(lang);
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    translate.changeText(translate.default);
});
```

Here's a [working demo of it on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TessaLiliana/s2Ldggs9/2/)

Comment: This is the best answer imo.

Comment: I realy like your solution. Unfortunately it gives me this error message:  Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined

Comment: Did you create the "translate" variable of objects? In the console, you should be able to type "translate.de.latitude" and it should give you the value of whatever you made it. I don't know German or French so I just left them as empty strings, but I Imagine you already have those values in your code to copy/paste into it.

Comment: If that works, then add in a "debugger" after capturing the value of the "lang" variable inside the listener, and make sure we're getting the right string.

Comment: I changed my code and it works fine now. If I might ask you another question, obviously I need to preselect a language before changing it. Otherwise there won't be any text at all. Can I simply set the lang var at the beginning so it only changes when I want it to change?

Comment: See my answer on how to do that.

Comment: See my JSFiddle for updated code that allows you run a default language on page load. https://jsfiddle.net/TessaLiliana/s2Ldggs9/2/

Comment: I used the 'checked' prefix but it only affected the radio button (checked). Still no text shown 
EDIT: I think it's ok if I just enter the english names as default text so it only changes the text when needed.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use the checked prefix at all because when the radio button is clicked, you know what button is checked at that time. Refresh the page or checkout the JSFiddle I added, and you'll see I included code snippets on how to get the default language on page load.

Comment: @Tessa Thats impressive. I would have thought about this in a hundred years. But I'm a beginner so I guess I learned an important lesson today.

Comment: That's the nicest thing anyone has said to me today! Thanks! We were all beginners at some point :) If there's one thing I've learned, there's about a million ways to do the same thing in programming, and most of them are right ;)

Comment: And most of them either work and you dont't know why or they don't work and don't know why :)
This probably applies to beginners only.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work that way, you need brackets notation.

```js
var words = {
  de: {
    lat: "Breitengrad",
    lon: "Längengrad"
  },
  en: {
    lat: "Latitude",
    lon: "Longitude"
  },
  fr: {}
};

function changeLanguage() {
  var lang = $('#lang-setting input:checked').val();
  $('#latitude-n').html(words[lang].lat);
}

$('#lang-setting input').click(changeLanguage);
changeLanguage();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lang-setting">
  <input type="radio" value="en" name="lang" checked>En</option>
  <input type="radio" value="de" name="lang">De</option>
  <input type="radio" value="fr" name="lang">Fr</option>
</div>
<p>
  <span id="latitude-n"></span>: <input />
</p>
```